# Empty when opened in new tab show and edit pages react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

When I click on the ShowButton with the wheel (I want to open in a new tab), the tab opens, but without content.
If I open by clicking the left mouse button - it opens in the same tab and everything is correct, if I click on the wheel, it opens in a new tab (as target=_blank) and in this case a blank page is displayed, without content. How can I fix it?

Simple ShowButton from React-admin
[image]

Actual
[image]

Expected
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.